# Why NavigationLink() stays open in SwiftUI 2

Tags: swift, swiftui, master-detail, swiftui-navigationlink

I have the following code. When app started **MasterView** is opening and then I click a row and going to **DetailView**. After I'm changing the tab in **RootTabView** to **OtherView**. And then when I turned back to the **MasterView** its automatically opens the **DetailView**.

Also both of `vm.getList()` and `vm.getDetail()` methods works. Why is that happening in **SwiftUI 2**? Because in **SwiftUI 1** it wasn't work like that.

```
struct RootTabView: View {
    @State var tabSelection = 0
    @State private var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            MasterView(vm: vm).tabItem({
                Text("Master")
            }).tag(0)
            
            OtherView().tabItem({
                Text("Other")
            }).tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct MasterView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(vm.toDoList, id: \.self) { toDo in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(vm: vm)) {
                    Text(toDo)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            vm.getList()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(vm.toDoItem)
            .onAppear {
                vm.getDetail()
            }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var toDoList: [String] = []
    @Published var toDoItem: String = ""
    
    func getList() {
        toDoList = ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
    
    func getDetail() {
        // do some stuffs
        toDoItem = "A"
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your description but here it *remains* on `DetailView` and this is expected behavior (and even logical - navigation state did not change, so last presented view is at top). Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Comment: @Asperi yes this is expected behavior but this is not same Xcode 11/ iOS 13.x. In iOS 13.x when the DetailView is open when I changed the tab to OtherView and then open the ListView again -> not showing DetailView. It shows ListView

Comment: That was bug, now it is fixed.

Comment: Also I tried in `onDisappear` action on the DetailView I set `presentationMode.dismiss()`. This time when open ListView again. It shows ListView. This part is OK. But I mentioned above `vm.getList()` and `vm.getDetail()` methods still works. I think this is not expected behavior